# Sqlalchemy with bulk_save_objects and declarative base does not add schema in sql

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am working with an Oracle database. The same table is in multiple schemas, and I have to copy data I get from an API to each schema. I created the code below and it works great the first time, but on the second save it does not add the schema name to the SQL, it only does it on the first save and I get an error.

```
import cx_Oracle

from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import VARCHAR2
from sqlalchemy                 import Column, Integer, Numeric
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine          import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url      import make_url
from sqlalchemy.orm             import Session
from sqlalchemy.exc             import DatabaseError

log = logging.getLogger('database')
Base = declarative_base()


class PROD(Base):
    """
    Schema for the database tables
 
    """
    __tablename__ = 'BIG_TABLE' 

    COMPANY_CODE            = Column(VARCHAR2(length=4), primary_key=True)
    REGION_CODE             = Column(VARCHAR2(length=5))
    PRODUCT_CODE            = Column(VARCHAR2(length=3))
 

class Database:
    session = None
    bulk_buffer = []

    def __init__(self, **config):
        self.schema = config.get('schema', '')
        self.name   = config.get('dbname', '')
        self.driver = config.get("driver", "oracle+cx_oracle")

        if 'wallet_string' in config:
            wallet = "/@{}_ggate".format(config['wallet_string'])
            url = make_url(f"{self.driver}:/{wallet}")

        elif 'host' in config and 'port' in config and 'service' in config:
            dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(config['host'], config['port'], service_name=config['service'])
            url = f"{self.driver}://{config['username']}:{config['password']}@{dsn}"

        self.engine = create_engine(url, max_identifier_length=128, threaded=True, echo=True)

    def open(self):
        self.session = Session(bind=self.engine)
        self.session.connection(execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {None: self.schema}})
        return self

    def close(self):
        self.session.close()
        self.engine.dispose()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.open()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        return self.close()

    def bulk_save(self, obj):
        """
        Bulk save multiple objects in a single shot.
        :param obj:
        :return:
        """
        self.bulk_buffer.append(obj)
        if len(self.bulk_buffer) == 2:
            try:
                self.session.bulk_save_objects(self.bulk_buffer)
                self.session.commit()
                ok= True
            except Exception as e:
                log.error("Database Exception {} adding ".format(str(e)))
                self.session.rollback()
                ok = False
            self.bulk_buffer.clear()
            return ok
        return True

    def flush(self):
        try:
            self.session.bulk_save_objects(self.bulk_buffer)
            self.session.commit()
            ok= True
        except Exception as e:
            log.error("Database Exception {} adding ".format(str(e)))
            self.session.rollback()
            ok = False
        self.bulk_buffer.clear()
        return ok
```

In my main code I have a loop that works like this, with config['schema'] = schema_name

```
       with Database(**config) as db:
         
            for result in results:
                for record in api():
                    p = PROD(**record)
                    db.bulk_save(p)
            db.flush()
```

On the first save it produces
2020-08-20 09:48:13,077 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "SCHEMA_NAME"."BIG_TABLE" (...

but one the next insert it produces
020-08-20 09:53:01,403 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "BIG_TABLE" (..

I need to to use the schema name every time or I get an error.

Comment: If all else fails, run explicit `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_USER = abc` commands.  This is ugly; maybe a sqlalchemy expert has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I do

```
        self.engine = create_engine(url, max_identifier_length=128, threaded=True, echo=True,execution_options = {'schema_translate_map':{None: self.schema}})
```

It works on each call